# Как правильно запустить Test.class из командной строки?

Tags: java, классы, cmd

Как правильно запустить Test.class из командной строки??? Test находится в пакетах ua.com.anzhurov . эти 3 пакпки находятся на рабочем столе. Вот фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Думаю, что проблема с тем, что нужно правильно указать имя -> ua.com.anzhurov.Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из каталога рабочего стола выполнить

```
java ua.com.anzhurov.Test
```